# Как получить домен и имя в формате DOMAIN/UserName пользователя по локальной сети

Tags: java, servlet

Пишу веб сервис с использованием сервлета.
На локальном компьютере отправляю POST-запрос сервлету.

Нужно получить домен и имя данного пользователя. Как это сделать? подскажите)

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, данные какого пользователя вы собираетесь получать.

Comment: У меня на работе есть локальная сеть, к которой подключены много рабочих компьютеров. И мне нужно получить домен и имя пользователя в локальной сети, для того, чтобы при изменении информации на веб-сервисе отображалось домен и имя пользователя который поправил инфу)

Comment: Если POST запрос формирует браузер, то откройте консоль и посмотрите на HTTP заголовки  - там все что вы можете получить. Если POST запрос формирует некое Java приложение, то оно может получить эти данные и передать их как параметры запроса.

Comment: Вот собственно и интересует как это реализовать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/473470/5694145

Comment: Пробовал уже так) 
У меня веб-сервис открывается по ip компьютера где запущен сервер.
Если заходить на него локально (с другого компьютера, браузера), то способ из Вашей ссылки получает данные только компьютера сервера. А вот мне нужно чтоб отправились данные удаленного пользователя. Может через js попробовать как-то?

Comment: Если клиент вашего веб приложения браузер - вы не получите имя пользователя на локальной машине. Потому что это дыра в безопаности. Если очень хочется, можете поднять в локальной сети Active Directory, чтобы пользователь входил на локальную машину как пользователь домена. И уже Active Directory использовать для аутентификации в веб приложении.